# google analytics noindex issue nextjs

Tags: next.js, google-analytics, analytics, next.js13

I've successfully added Google Analytics to my Next.js 13.5 project, and it's working well, showing me the pages users are visiting. However, I've encountered an issue where the `<meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>` tag is being added automatically. As a result, when I attempt to index my website, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

// GoogleAnalytics

```
import Script from "next/script";
import { usePathname, useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { pageview } from "@/lib/gtagHelper";

export default function GoogleAnalytics() {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();

  const GA_MEASUREMENT_ID = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GA_TRACKING_ID}`;
  useEffect(() => {
    const url = pathname + searchParams.toString();

    pageview(GA_MEASUREMENT_ID, url);
  }, [pathname, searchParams, GA_MEASUREMENT_ID]);

  return (
    <>
      <Script
        async
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        src={`https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}`}
      />
      <Script
        async
        id="google-analytics"
        strategy="afterInteractive"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
                window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                gtag('js', new Date());

                gtag('consent', 'default', {
                    'analytics_storage': 'granted'
                });
                
                gtag('config', '${GA_MEASUREMENT_ID}', {
                    page_path: window.location.pathname,
                });
                `,
        }}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

---

//Pageview

```
export const pageview = (GA_MEASUREMENT_ID: string, url: string) => {
  window.gtag("config", GA_MEASUREMENT_ID, {
    page_path: url,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export metadata from your layout page with all metadata tags as objects using the Metadata Nextjs component.

```js
import type { Metadata } from 'next'


export const metadata:Metadata = {
  robots: {
    index: true,
    googleBot: {
      index: true,
    },
  },
};
```

This will override the default generated meta tags from the NextJS server and have a lot of other customizations.